# How to modifiy the code for send a message without attachement?

Tags: php

i need to send a message on my script but without an attachement because when i don't attach a file, i get this error :
"Error : your file must be type :3MF/STL/OBJ/PLY/STP/SVG/DXF/IGS/PDF/JPEG/PNG ou DOC."

I have tried some example on internet but i'm stucked here.

```
<?php
$errormsg = "";

if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $errormsg .= "Name required. ";
} else {
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errormsg .= "Email required. ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

/*if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $errormsg .= "Phone required. ";
} else {
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
}*/
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

if (empty($_POST["service"])) {
    @$service .= "";
} else {
    $service = $_POST["service"];
}

if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errormsg .= "Message required. ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}

if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 104857666) {
        $errormsg .= "Votre fichier ne dois pas faire plus de 100 MO. ";
    }

    $allowed =  array('3mf','stl' ,'OBJ','PLY','STP','svg','dxf','igs','pdf','jpeg','png','doc');
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
        $errormsg .= "Votre fichier doit être de type 3MF/STL/OBJ/PLY/STP/SVG/DXF/IGS/PDF/JPEG/PNG ou DOC. ";
    }
}

$success = '';
if (!$errormsg){

    require_once "mgs-functions.php";

    //email subject (Change here)
    if($subject)
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
    else
        $mail->Subject = "Nouvelle demande de devis !";

    $mgsetemple = false;        //Boolean true/false    true: email template    false: plain text email
    $body_message = "";
    if(!$mgsetemple) {
        //prepare email body [for Plain email use this]
        $body_message .= "Adresse IP du client: " . get_client_ip() ."<br>";
        $body_message .= "Nom et prénom du client: " . $fname ."<br>";
        $body_message .= "Adresse e-mail du client: " . $email ."<br>";
        $body_message .= "Numéro de téléphone du client: " . $phone ."<br>";
        $body_message .= "Service voulu: " . $service ."<br>";
        $body_message .= "\n\n". $message;
    }
    else{           
        //prepare email body [Using email template]
        $body_message = file_get_contents('mgsc-email-template/mgsc-email-template.php');
        $mgsemailshorttag = array("[mgs-sender-ip]", "[mgs-sender-name]", "[mgs-sender-email]", "[mgs-sender-phone]", "[mgs-sender-service]", "[mgs-sender-message]");
        $mgsemailshorttagvalue   = array(get_client_ip(), $fname, $email, $phone, $service, $message);
        $body_message = str_replace($mgsemailshorttag, $mgsemailshorttagvalue, $body_message);
    }

    $mail->Body = $body_message;

    if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {

        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $sname = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $fname));
        $uploadfile = 'uploads/' . substr( base_convert( time(), 10, 36 ) . md5( microtime() ), 0, 8 ). '-' . $sname . '.' . $ext;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            // Attach the uploaded file
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $sname .'file-'. $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        }

    }   

    //send mail
    if(!$mail->send()) 
    {           
        //delete files from server
        if (file_exists($uploadfile)){
            unlink($uploadfile);
        }
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } 
    else 
    {
        //delete files from server
        if (file_exists($uploadfile)){
            unlink($uploadfile);
        }
        echo "Votre fichier est parvenu jusqu'à nos techniciens, merci !";
    }

}
else {
    echo "Erreur: ".$errormsg;
}
```

?>

I have tried some tips but don't work yet

Answer (score 0):

My form processor is a all-config-in-form type generic processor.  For handling attachments, while I don't discriminate against file types I do have to generate different headers, etc. for sending a plain message vs. message w/ file(s) attached.  To detect them, I check to see if there is a $_FILES element that has an error code of 0 (no errors), if so add that element to a new array, and then later process that new array when actually adding the attachments.

Here's how I do it...

```
$hasFile=false;
foreach($_FILES as $k=>$v){
    if($v['error']===0){
        $hasFile=true;
        $attachments[]=$v;
    }
}
```

Then later,

```
if($hasFile){
      // build headers for sending w/ attachment and process attachments to add
}else{
      // build headers for regular message
}
```